# Llamar a una clase desde una función en JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo una clase en JavaScript que necesito llamar desde una función (JavaScript/JQuery) pero me da error ya que no la reconoce, sólo me funciona cuando la llamo desde cualquier evento del mouse: click, blur, focus, etc.

```
class brandObject {

    constructor() {
        this.article_brand_active = $('.tile-motorbike-brands').hasClass('active');
        this.articleBrandContainer = $('.tile-motorbike-brands');
        this.articleBrandTitle = $('#title-brand');
        this.btnNewBrand = $('#btn-new-motorbike-brand');
        this.btnListBrand = $('#btn-list-motorbike-brand');
        this.iconBrand = $('.icon-brand');
    }

    NBHover() {
        this.articleBrandTitle.css('background-color','rgb(76, 175, 80)');
        this.btnNewBrand.css('color','rgb(76, 175, 80)');
        this.btnListBrand.css('color','rgb(189, 189, 189)');
        this.iconBrand.css('color','rgb(76, 175, 80)');
        
        $('#title-brand').removeClass('listBrandActiveBGColor');
        $('.icon-brand').removeClass('listBrandActiveColor');
    }

    NBLeave() {
        this.articleBrandTitle.css('background-color','rgb(43, 174, 168)');
        this.btnNewBrand.css('color','rgb(189, 189, 189)');
        this.btnListBrand.css('color','rgb(189, 189, 189)');
        this.iconBrand.css('color','rgba(43, 174, 168, 0.4)');
    }

    NBActived() {
        this.articleBrandContainer.addClass('actived');
        this.articleBrandTitle.addClass('newBrandActiveBGColor');
        this.btnNewBrand.addClass('newBrandActiveColor');
        this.btnListBrand.css('color','rgb(189, 189, 189)');
        this.iconBrand.addClass('newBrandActiveColor');
    }

}
```

Llamada a la clase que sí funciona:

```
$('#btn-new-motorbike-brand').on({
    mouseenter: function() {
        newSelected('brands','active');
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
        newSelected('brands','inactive');
    },
    click: function() {
        var activarNewBrand = new brandObject();
        activarNewBrand.NBActived();
    }
});
```

Si utilizo una función en el evento click del botón desde el código HTML me dice que la clase no existe.

```
function brandObject() {

    var activarNewBrand = new brandObject();
    activarNewBrand.NBActived();

}
```

¿Será que no se puede llamar desde una función? He buscado en internet pero no hay nada parecido, sólo ejemplos de como hacer las clases.

Comment: tienes todo el código separado en archivos?? Como agregas a tu html los script??

Comment: exportas la clase al final del documento?

Comment: jorge Gomez no hay problema con los demás scripts, se cargan perfectamente y funcionan, es sólo con la clase que el navegador no la reconoce cuando la llamo desde una función, si la llamo desde un evento del mouse funciona bien.

Comment: AQMR la clase está al principio, se carga primero que los demás los scripts.

Comment: Probaste utilizar un nombre diferente para tu función? Se llama exactamente igual que la clase, tal vez eso este causando el problema

Comment: Camilo Gomez el código se me fue con un error de tipeo, la función tiene otro nombre e igual no funciona